# RavenDb Spatial Query

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

We are moving from MongoDb to RavenDb, and ran into an issue.

We have a simple model (C# DotNet)

```
using System.Globalization;

public class Location 
{
    #region Properties

    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Methods

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var numberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." };

        return $"{Longitude.ToString(numberFormatInfo)} {Latitude.ToString(numberFormatInfo)}";
    }

    #endregion Methods
}

public class Place
{
    public Location[] Area {get;set;} // Please note the array
}
```

A customer can either select a place as a single pair, or they can draw a polygon on an interactive map, which represents the place, that would get stored in the Area property above.

In MongoDb this could not have been simpler

```
var locationQuery = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Place>()
.GeoWithinBox(
 field: x => x.Area,
 lowerLeftX: query.Criteria.LongitudeBottomLeft,
 lowerLeftY: query.Criteria.LatitudeBottomLeft,
 upperRightX: query.Criteria.LongitudeTopRight,
 upperRightY: query.Criteria.LatitudeTopRight);
```

The query class above, represents the currently visible area on the map, the customer is looking at.

Despite my best attempts, I cannot decipher the documentation on how to achieve the same.
I am hoping someone may be able to shed some light on the matter, on how one would achieve this using the
RavenDb Dotnet client (RavenDB.Client)

Thanks

**Update & Sample**!

After the great answer below from Ayende Rahien, I thought I would add some details here in attempt to simplify the journey for others landing here.

This is what the index looked like.

```
using System.Linq;

using Raven.Client.Documents.Indexes;

public class PlaceAreaIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Place>
{
    public PlaceAreaIndex()
    {
        Map = places => from place in places
                        select new
                        {
                            Area = place.Area.Select(location => CreateSpatialField(location.Latitude, location.Longitude))
                        };
    }
}
```

You will need to register your index on the server, before using the query.

```
new PlaceAreaIndex().Execute(store);
```

I added some helper classes to assist me testing this out, I am adding them here so the sample gets you as close as possible to a running code

```
public class Box
{
    #region Constructor

    public Box(Location topRight, Location bottomLeft)
    {
        TopRight = topRight;
        BottomLeft = bottomLeft;

        TopLeft = new Location { Latitude = topRight.Latitude, Longitude = bottomLeft.Longitude };
        BottomRight = new Location { Latitude = bottomLeft.Latitude, Longitude = topRight.Longitude };
    }

    #endregion Constructor

    #region Properties

    public Location TopRight { get;}
    public Location TopLeft { get; }
    public Location BottomLeft { get; }
    public Location BottomRight { get; }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Methods

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"POLYGON (({TopRight}, {TopLeft}, {BottomLeft}, {BottomRight}, {TopRight}))";
    }

    #endregion Methods
}
```

Then using the helpers

```
var topRight = Location.New(latitude: -22.674847351188916, longitude: 31.25061035156253);
var bottomLeft = Location.New(latitude: -28.9600886880069, longitude: 25.1422119140623);
var box = new Box(topRight: topRight, bottomLeft: bottomLeft);
```

After that you can query it like this

```
var places = await session
    .Query<Place, PlaceAreaIndex>()
    .Spatial(
        factory => factory.Area,
        criteria => criteria.RelatesToShape(
            shapeWkt: box.ToString(),
            relation: SpatialRelation.Within))
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: You can see a **dynamic query** example that queries on a Polygon area here:
https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/e6164ad9938fb2922fdc19a68b6c1f8a6cdc6d64/test/SlowTests/Tests/Spatial/DynamicSpatialQueries.cs#L286


Note: the polygon start and end points locations must be the same, and points must be in counterclockwise order

Comment: Hi Danielle, thank you for that link. I did see that one, and still could not work out how that applies to the array that is being stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, the issue is that you may have a specific location or a polygon, right?
When representing a polygon in RavenDB, you need to use WKT for that.

For example, here is what this looks like:

```
POLYGON((14.316406249999982 37.541615344157876,32.68554687499998 37.541615344157876,32.68554687499998 25.439901234431595,14.316406249999982 25.439901234431595,14.316406249999982 37.541615344157876))
```

This can then be used by the spatial engine inside of RavenDB and allow you to query using `spatial.Contains`.

However, that might not be what you want, depending on usage.

If what you want is simply to find all the `Places` that has *a* Location inside a rectangle, it would be easier to just threat this as an array of locations.
On the other hand, if this is really a polygon, that is different.

Might be easier to show things. The sample data in RavenDB has spatial data, like so:

```
$wkt = "POLYGON((-1.0800308814195025 51.942980464942416,0.5789046654554975 51.942980464942416,0.5789046654554975 51.01935531918276,-1.0800308814195025 51.01935531918276,-1.0800308814195025 51.942980464942416))"
from Employees 
where spatial.within( spatial.point(Address.Location.Latitude , Address .Location.Longitude), 
    spatial.wkt($wkt))
```

And you can then see the new spatial tab which will show you the results:

[image: Spatial query results, map view]

This shows the rectangle (wkt) and a single point.

However, if you have an array, you can also use:

```
    "Locations": [
        {
            "Latitude": 51.52384070000001,
            "Longitude": -0.0944233
        },
        {
            "Latitude": 51.48145355123356,
            "Longitude": -0.17475717569860105
        }
    ],
```

That, however, need an explicit index to handle, you can write it like so:

```
from e in docs.Employees
select new 
{
    Locations = e.Locations.Select(l => CreateSpatialField(l.Latitude, l.Longitude))
}
```

This index all individual locations for an employee.

And then you can query it using:

```
$wkt = "POLYGON((-1.0800308814195025 51.942980464942416,0.5789046654554975 51.942980464942416,0.5789046654554975 51.01935531918276,-1.0800308814195025 51.01935531918276,-1.0800308814195025 51.942980464942416))"
from index 'Employees/ByLocations'
where spatial.within( Locations, spatial.wkt($wkt))
```

The other option, however, is when you need to turn the list of locations into a ploygon.
For example, consider this WKT:
`POLYGON((-0.09345874990495329 51.7543103056377,-0.6823256691840518 51.56348306507395,-0.2252946874049533 51.30046869394702,0.09990102742639895 51.42120466591834,-0.09345874990495329 51.7543103056377))`

This represents this polygon:

[image: Map representation of previous WKT]

You can then use the same style of query as before, but be aware:

- Your `contains` query now need to include the *entire* polygon. You can use `intersect` as well, but then you are probably better off with the single points option.
- You need to be aware of the *order* of points in WKT. It matters. You need counter clockwise.